# Breaking an old clickonce app so nobody can use it? (Remotely uninstalling all installations?)

Tags: .net, vb.net, deployment, clickonce

I have an old ClickOnce program, which has been replaced by a new one I wrote, and I am aware that some people are still using the old one.

I want to somehow remotely remove it from every computer where it is still being used (there are far too many to manually find them).

I don't want to make an update that will stop it from working, as they may not decide to install the update.

Is there a way to change the manifest file on the server so when the applications check for an update, they will not open?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best thing to do is to publish an update to the old application and have it uninstall itself. The blog post referred to by Adam has a couple of bugs in it; [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff369721.aspx) is an article I wrote for MSDN that was tested and sanctioned by Microsoft that includes code for uninstalling an application. I've used it several times, even for VSTO applications.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, when a ClickOnce app encounters a problem during the auto-update process, it will just silently fail and run the previous version from disk.  I don't think there's anything you could change in the manifest to get the application to fail altogether.

When your aplication starts up, does it have any external dependencies, like a shared config file?  You could remove access to a resource like that to prevent the application from starting up.

Another option would be to automate the uninstall process of the old app and direct the user to your new application.  Here's a [blog post](http://www.jamesharte.com/blog/?p=11) that should help if you go that route.